# How to print VIM current color scheme?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

My color file is quite complicated. I think it detects my term and generates color values on the fly.

Is there any way I can print out the generated colors?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This command will open a new window containing all highlight group names, displayed
in their own colour:

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim
```

or

```
:runtime syntax/hitest.vim
```

Then this command will turn it into an equivalent HTML file (note capital Tee Oh)

```
:TOhtml
```

Save the file and print it out in the usual way from your favourite browser.

Comment: Thanks! This is even better than last answer ;)

Comment: BTW: An easier command to use is `:runtime syntax/hitest.vim`

Answer (score 52):

- Type `:color` to view current color-scheme.
- Type `:hi` to list all color groups.
- Type `:hi Statement` to view color definations for *Statement*. (change *Statement* to what you want)

Comment: To know the value of `Statement`, see Revealing Syntax Groups section in this http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/.

Answer (score 1):

I have Vim 8 you use `:colo`, `:color` or `:colorscheme`